# Is str_replace function will be enough to secure this code?

Tags: php, security

I want to allow users read files in their directory (and subdirectories) with GET param. I have to secure this part of code, so they cannot go to upper directories with two dots. Will it be enough?

```
$filePath = $userDir . '/' . str_replace( '..', '', $_GET['path'] );

if(!is_file($filePath)) {
    die();
}

readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: This may be personal preference, but I wouldn't let them choose the path at all (directly anyway). My suggestion is store the filenames (and fake path if you like) in a database, with a link to the real file on your filesystem. If they put in a valid file, then `readfile` the real file... if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I agree with you, but unfortunately I'm not able to change database structure.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing ../ and ..\, since .. by itself could be part of a valid filename like "abc..xyz.txt"

Answer (score -1):

Be careful here!

Even if you replace "../" and "..\", make sure you do it **recursively**. Because if you don't, a malicious user can submit the following to bypass your security:

"..././"

```
$path = '..././';
var_dump(str_replace('../', '', $path));
// string(3) "../"
```

See the problem here?

You can use a do/while loop to sanitise the user input in a secure manner:

```
$path = '..././';

do {
    $path = str_replace(['../', '..\\'], '', $path, $count);
} while ($count > 0);

var_dump($path);
// string(0) ""
```

But I'm with Jon on this. It's usually not a good idea to allow this, and avoid it whenever possible. Be as restrictive as you can with the filenames. Always prepend the user path instead of passing the full path via URL param.